# Command Button is changing names when different version of Excel opens it

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a spreadsheet that was created in Excel 2010 Pro Plus.  I was just recently upgraded at my business to the Pro Plus version. It is very simple and it works when I open and use it. However, when I send it to my colleagues, they open it, click to enable macros, and immediately it tells them my VBA does not work. It says that the object cannot be found.

Thinking it was a problem with my code, I did a test. I created a spreadsheet with one Active X command button. I assigned it the code:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2").value = sheet1.Range("A2").value + 1
```

Just the simplest command I could think of. I opened it on my version of excel and it worked. Yet still, when my colleagues opened it it gave them the compile error, object does not exist. When looking into the error I found 2 things:

1. When I create a command button in a spreadsheet in my new excel version, it starts with "CommandButton21" This seems odd because if I remember correctly, excel should always start with "CommandButton1" and go in sequential order. Why is it putting a "2" between the CommandButton and the "1"
2. The reason my colleagues are getting the compile error object not found is because when they open the spreadsheet, it changes the name of the active x command button from "CommandButton21" to "CommandButton22".

I ran another test to confirm this. I opened a new spreadsheet on a COLLEAGUES computer and wrote the same code with the same command button (except when I created the command button, it was in fact "CommandButton1" not "CommandButton21" like my version is doing). After creating the spreadsheet, i sent it to my version of excel. It worked. So, I created the exact same spreadsheet on my version, same code, and I even renamed the button "CommandButton1". I sent it to my Colleague and it still didnt work.

Please someone, tell me this is an installation error or something. Before the Pro Plus version, everything worked fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im no expert at VBA, just a novice, but i have done plenty of macros to know this is not normal.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a Form Control instead of an ActiveX one? They have proven much more stable and compatible across systems for me. As a guess to the specific issue you're experiencing, there is an issue with ActiveX controls when moving between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility

Comment: Thank you for the response. Both versions are 32 bit versions of excel. I was reluctant to use form controls just for aesthetics of the Active X controls. I had always heard they had compatibility issues, but had never seen it first hand. I will take your advice and use a form control. I wish I knew what the problem was though, since we both use 32 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

Apply fm20.dll fix from Microsoft for Microsoft Office 2010. If you have Office 2013, then apply both fm20.dll fix for both 2010 and 2013.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx